# Jquery Validation - onkeyup doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am having some difficulty with the following validation, in that it doesn't activate the validation check until you click on an area on the page, away from the form element.

It should be onkeyup but doesn't work.  This is the case for the 3 forms fields listed.

Title is a select list
Name is a standard input text field
Bday is a input field using a jquery datetimepicker

```
$(document).ready(function($){

    var validator = $("#register").validate({
        rules: {
            title: {
                required: true
            },
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            bday: {
                 required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            title: "Select a title",
            name: {
                required: "Provide a name"
            },
            bday: "Provide your birth date"
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where are you defining your event listener? Are you using a validation plugin? Have you checked the console for any JS errors.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant, as I had commented it out in my code but I did have the following  submitHandler: function() {
         alert("submitted!");
      },

Answer (score 0):

try this : `$(document).ready('keyup', function($){`

Comment: Thanks for your input but this stopped the validation working completely.